# Cannot retrieve rows from Zend_Db_Table_Rowset

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I have successfully fetched a rowset from my database table unto the view script. I did a `var_dump($result)` on the view script to confirm. But I am unable to fetch the individual rows to properly display their contents.

```
<?php
if($this->result)
    while($data =$this->result->getRow())
        var_dump($data);
```

I get the error message(truncated..):

```
Message: No row could be found at position 0 
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\events\application\views\scripts\event\fetch.phtml(6): Zend_Db_Table_Rowset_Abstract->getRow()
....
....
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally got it sorted. The `getRow()` method apparently does not work with `while()` loops. I switched to `foreach()` loop and it's resolved.

Though I would still like to know why the `while()` loop does not work.